# Upload picture directly to the server

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript

In the following link http://www.tuttoaster.com/create-a-camera-application-in-flash-using-actionscript-3/ how to make the picture upload directly to the server after taking a picture from webcam

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

public class caml extends Sprite
{
    private var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
    private var video:Video = new Video();
    private var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(320,240);
    private var bmp:Bitmap;
    private var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
    private var byteArray:ByteArray;
    private var jpg:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();

    public function caml()
    {
        saveButton.visible = false;
        discardButton.visible = false;

        saveButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, saveImage);
        discardButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, discard);
        capture.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, captureImage);

        if (camera != null)
        {
            video.smoothing = true;
            video.attachCamera(camera);
            video.x = 140;
            video.y = 40;
            addChild(video);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("No Camera Detected");
        }
    }
        private function captureImage(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            bmd.draw(video);
            bmp = new Bitmap(bmd);
            bmp.x = 140;
            bmp.y = 40;
            addChild(bmp);

            capture.visible = false;
            saveButton.visible = true;
            discardButton.visible = true;
        }

        private function saveImage(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            byteArray = jpg.encode(bmd);
            fileReference.save(byteArray, "Image.jpg");
            removeChild(bmp);
            saveButton.visible = false;
            discardButton.visible = false;
            capture.visible = true;
        }

        private function discard(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            removeChild(bmp);
            saveButton.visible = false;
            discardButton.visible = false;
            capture.visible = true;
        }


}
 }
```

Comment: I feel like this question can be answered a million different ways.  Do you want to upload to a popular photo service? (Flickr, Picasa, etc)  Or do you want to upload to YOUR server?  If so, what is your backend technology?  Do you have any type of web service interface?  I don't think we can answer your question without more information...

Comment: Hi,I want to upload it to my server and the backend technology i am using is Django(python).As soon as the pic is taken i get a option to save instead i can give a upload button and save it on server.

Comment: @Rajeev: Can you show us the code you are calling to take the picture?

Comment: You can use FileReference.upload() to upload to a server, it has to be GET or POST but I don't know Django so I can't write a sample snippet for that.

Comment: Can u indicate on PHP if u are familiar with it or any other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileReference.upload() and FileReference.download() functions are nonblocking. These functions return after they are called, before the file transmission is complete. In addition, if the FileReference object goes out of scope, any upload or download that has not yet been completed on that object is cancelled upon leaving the scope. So, be sure that your FileReference object will remain in scope for as long as the upload or download could be expected to continue. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001063.html